# ARM assembler directive (macro) IF statement

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm using some of the ARM Assembler Directives when I compile my assembler.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
                GBLA count
count           SETA 0

                WHILE count <=1024

                IF count = {50}
                    ; Do something special here
                ENDIF

count           SETA count+1
                ; Repetitive code here


                WEND
```

But I get the error message:
error: AA1198E: Unknown operand.

I've tried prepending the IF statement with count, in case that did it, but I get a different error.

Unfortunately the [ARM documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ARMASMREF/armasmref_cacbjgdb.htm) on this isn't great (or I'm not very clever, which is more than likely hehe)

Comment: shot in the dark...take the { } away from around the 50. `IF count = 50`

Comment: Oh whoops. Guess I was taking the documentation a bit too literally. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the { } away from around the 50.

```
IF count = 50
```